# How can I convert my Tkinter application to a web application?

Tags: python, django, tkinter, web-applications

I wrote a simple application with Tkinter which gets data from an .xlsc file and converts it to a document file. Now, I want to distribute my application as a web application. Can I do it without using Django? There’s a similar question but I couldn’t understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

Long answer: Not exactly. Below's why

You'd have to rewrite the UI using any of the available web front end technologies. You can however, utilize most of the backend you've written, with some adjustments according to a web app. Django is a fine choice, flask is great if the project isn't very large.

Also Note that web applications introduce many different variables which are not a concern in desktop applications like user security, isolation of user specific process/tasks if any, authentication etc to name a few.